# STM32 timer interrupt initialization

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, stm32

I'm trying to initialize a timer interrupt in STM32.

I'm using following timers:
TIM2 to create a Second/100ms/10ms time periods.
TIM3 to make a sound signals (buzzer) without `delay()`
TIM4 to create a PWM signal for my motors (multycopter motors)
TIM10 to make 1us counts

Idea is:
PWM signal of TIM4 drives a motor >
the motor-propeller interrupts a light-gate >
interrupt counter of STM32 will be increased >
TIM10 counts microseconds >
TIM2 counts (for example) 1s and get every 1s timer-interrupt-IRQ >
after 1s: counted microseconds will be divided by interrupt counter = mean time between propeller rotation >
mean time will send via serial interface (UART) to PC and saved.

The problem: then I activate a timer IRQ Handler of TIM2 `TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);`

I lose my PWM signal of TIM4. Why it is happens? 
Its a right initialization of timer interrupt? 
I don't need a polling. Any corrections?

```
// *************************************************************************
// Initialisation for motor PWM and timer 4

void Motor_PWM_Init(void) {

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13
            | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_TIM4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_TIM4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_TIM4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_TIM4);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef Timer_InitStructure;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef Output_ChannelInit;

    uint16_t PrescalarValue = (uint16_t) 84 - 1;

    Timer_InitStructure.TIM_Period = 20000 - 1;
    Timer_InitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = PrescalarValue;
    Timer_InitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
    Timer_InitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &Timer_InitStructure);

    Output_ChannelInit.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    Output_ChannelInit.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    Output_ChannelInit.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    Output_ChannelInit.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;

    TIM_OC1Init(TIM4, &Output_ChannelInit);
    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

    TIM_OC2Init(TIM4, &Output_ChannelInit);
    TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

    TIM_OC3Init(TIM4, &Output_ChannelInit);
    TIM_OC3PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

    TIM_OC4Init(TIM4, &Output_ChannelInit);
    TIM_OC4PreloadConfig(TIM4, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM4, ENABLE);

    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}

// *************************************************************************
// Initialisation for buzzer PWM and timer 3

void Buzzer_PWM_Init(void) {

    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioStructure;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, ENABLE);

    gpioStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    gpioStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpioStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_TIM3);


    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timerInitStructure;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef outputChannelInit;

    uint16_t PrescalarValue = (uint16_t) 84-1;

    timerInitStructure.TIM_Period = 1000 - 1;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = PrescalarValue;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &timerInitStructure);

    outputChannelInit.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    outputChannelInit.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    outputChannelInit.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    outputChannelInit.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;

    TIM_OC1Init(TIM3, &outputChannelInit);
    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM3, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM3, ENABLE);

    TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);
}

// *************************************************************************
// Initialisation for timer 10 (1 usecond timer)

void MicroSek_timer_Init() {

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure;

    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_TIM10); // PB8 -> TIM10 Channel 1


    // TIM10 Clock enable
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM10, ENABLE);

    // Timer 10 Config PWM

    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF; //Change Orig 1 Sek: 10000-1; 1ms: 10-1; 10ms: 100-1; 100ms: 1000-1
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 84-1; //Change Orig 1 Sek: 16800-1
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM10, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);

    TIM_OCStructInit(&TIM_OCInitStructure);
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_Low;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM10, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM10, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM10, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM10, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM10, ENABLE);

    TIM10->CCR1 = 1<<15;

}


// *************************************************************************
// Initialisation for timer 2 (1 second timer)

void FS_timer_Init() {

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource0, GPIO_AF_TIM2); // PC6 -> TIM8 Channel 1


    // TIM2 Clock enable
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    // Timer 2 Config PWM

    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = period - 1; //Change Orig 1 Sek: 10000-1; 1ms: 10-1; 10ms: 100-1; 100ms: 1000-1
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 8400-1; //Change Orig 1 Sek: 16800-1
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);

    TIM_OCStructInit(&TIM_OCInitStructure);
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_Low;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM2, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM2, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM2, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
//  TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM2, ENABLE);

    TIM2->CCR1 = period/2;

    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x01;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);

}

// *************************************************************************
// FS-Timer interrupt

void TIM2_IRQHandler(){
    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
        {
            TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update);

            fs_cnt++;
            ov_flag = TRUE;
            fs_flag = TRUE;

            uint32_t time = TIM10->CNT;
            uint32_t t_mean_0 = time/interruptcounter0;
            uint32_t t_mean_1 = time/interruptcounter1;
            uint32_t t_mean_2 = time/interruptcounter2;
            uint32_t t_mean_3 = time/interruptcounter3;

            char uart_t_mean_0[6];
            char uart_t_mean_1[6];
            char uart_t_mean_2[6];
            char uart_t_mean_3[6];

            itoa(t_mean_0, uart_t_mean_0, 6);
            itoa(t_mean_1, uart_t_mean_1, 6);
            itoa(t_mean_2, uart_t_mean_2, 6);
            itoa(t_mean_3, uart_t_mean_3, 6);

            USART2_Send(USART2, uart_t_mean_0);
            USART2_Send(USART2, "\n");

            USART2_Send(USART2, uart_t_mean_1);
            USART2_Send(USART2, "\n");

            USART2_Send(USART2, uart_t_mean_2);
            USART2_Send(USART2, "\n");

            USART2_Send(USART2, uart_t_mean_3);
            USART2_Send(USART2, "\n");

            TIM10->CNT = 0;

            interruptcounter0=0;
            interruptcounter0=1;
            interruptcounter0=2;
            interruptcounter0=3;

            }
    else{

        fs_flag = FALSE;
    }
}
```